# Referencing `@Configuration` bean of enum type in `@ConditionalOnExpression`

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I define a `Job` enum in my application as:

```java
package org.example;

public enum Job {
    JOB_1, JOB_2, JOB_3
}
```

And create a Bean of the same type inside a class annotated with `@Configuration`:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Job jobType(@Value("${app.job.type}") Job jobType) {
        return jobType;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The value used for creating said bean is drawn from the `application.properties`:

```
app.job.type=${APP_JOB:JOB_1}
```

While the bean creation works fine, what I want to do next is create a `@Component` conditionally based on the value of the bean. So far I've tried:

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{ T(org.example.Job).JOB_1.equals(jobType) }")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Autowired)
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
public class FirstJobComponent {

    Job jobType;

    // ...

}
```

But this results in an exception:

```
2023-07-12 13:39:41.240 ERROR 83861 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/_redacted_/target/classes/org/example/FirstJobComponent.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.example.FirstJobComponent
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:457) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:295) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:748) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.example.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.example.FirstJobComponent
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:88) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:71) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isConditionMatch(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:512) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:495) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:430) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobType' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnExpressionCondition.evaluateExpression(OnExpressionCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnExpressionCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnExpressionCondition.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobType' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:223) ~[spring-expression-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:106) ~[spring-expression-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:93) ~[spring-expression-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getArguments(MethodReference.java:164) ~[spring-expression-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueRef(MethodReference.java:81) ~[spring-expression-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:71) ~[spring-expression-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92) ~[spring-expression-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114) ~[spring-expression-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:273) ~[spring-expression-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:167) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

What could be the cause of this? Does the `@ConditionalOnExpression` get evaluated before the bean is defined? I thought that it would cause a bean to get defined early if it does not exist. The Spring Expression Language reference is not very helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.10/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) annotations are used to determine whether a bean is going to be registered or not, therefore when conditions are evaluated the bean does not exist yet.

The way to solve your issue is to refer to the `app.job.type` in the SpEL expression, as follows:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{T(com.example.Job).JOB_1.toString().equals('${app.job.type}')}")
```

Comment: I can confirm that a SpEL expression like `"#{T(org.example.Job).valueOf('${app.job.type}') == T(org.example.Job).CODE}"` works. But I'm still curious, if this is not possible with `Conditional` is there another method or annotation for creating components based on the values of a bean?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm curious, how would you use `FirstJobComponent`? Since it will exist only when the condition is matched, how would you handle the case when the component doesn't exist?

Comment: I would not "use" it anywhere. It's not shown in the example but the component's `run()` method is annotated with `@Scheduled`. If the bean does not exist, the scheduled task should not spawn (which is already the current behaviour). I guess the alternative would be to schedule `Runnable` instances in a dedicated `Configuration` class, based on the bean value. I hope what I'm saying makes sense.

Comment: I get it. Runnable is probably the alternative, but I still think it is better to use `ConditionalOnExpression` mentioned in the answer. In that case, the` jobType` bean is unnecessary, since it can be injected into the component using `@Value` in the constructor.

Comment: In the end, I decided to use the solution based on your first comment. I wish that you could use bean references in the annotation, as it would make the expression less verbose. But I understand it's not possible. Since there are no other proposed solutions, and mine is based on your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @OzrenDabić have you found a better solution?